# How do I debug problems during Azure Store offer upgrade?

Tags: azure, azure-store

I'm having troubles debugging "upgrade" of my offer in Azure Store. I've "purchased" the offering, then I click "Upgrade", select a more expensive plan and click the "Proceed" arrow I see the following error message:

> We cannot provide a billing estimate at this time. Please try again later. If this error persists, contact support with the following information.
>   (Subscription could not be found for the provided subscription id (DM - ActivityId={GuidHere}

On my service side I see that there's a `GET` to `/storebase/subscriptions/sub-id-here/cloudservices/service-name-here` to which my service returns an XML reply together with `HTTP 200`.

That's all the data I have.

How do I find why the upgrade process fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is there's no way to actually debug something because there's no way to access Azure Store logs and no way to find what happens behind the scene when the user goes from one Azure Store purchase step to another. All the developer can do is contact support.